# Fsharp Ionide on VS code: new tests not recognised until project reload

Tags: f#, ionide

I am running an Fsharp console project on VS Code using the Ionide plugin. I added a test file using Xunit. However when I add a new test to the test file, the test case only gets recognized when I reload the window using the command pallette.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the tests are listed on the left hand side inside the test menu and each test case has a run button. But in order for these to appear on a new test case I have to reload the window.
Is there a way I can make Ionide recognize the tests without a window reload?

Comment: I can confirm that this is also happening to me. For the record, I am using a class library project for the main code and an xunit test project in the same solution. I was ripping my hair out until I saw this post.

Comment: I reported the bug on Github [here](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/1892)